# ASP.NET clicking on button after changing textbox, firing client event and server event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a popup for change an address with 3 text box (Address, Province and ZIP) and one DropDownList for the City. Changing the ZIP code it change the province text box with an ajax call, and I want to add later populate city ddl, if I can get it work. The problem is that if I now change the ZIP code, then click outside of it and then click the save button is working good, I've the correct value in the server side function, but if I change the ZIP code and then click directly to the save button I could see the Province text changing correctly in the interface too, but in the btnSave_Click it still have the old value. I've tried to make not async the ajax call, but still nothing..

ASPX:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Address</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Province</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProvince" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>City</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>ZIP Code</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtZIP" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><asp:Label id="lblError" runat="server" style="color:Red" Visible="false" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnResidenza" ImageUrl="/Images/Button/salva.png" runat="server"
                    OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('change', 'input[id*="txtZIP"]', function () {
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "CleanAddress.aspx/txtZIP_TextChanged",
                data: "{ZIP:'" + $("[id*='txtZIP']").val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("[id*=txtProvince]").val(response.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Errore! " + result.status + " - " + result.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Web Method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string txtZIP_TextChanged(string ZIP)
{
    if ((ZIP.Trim() != "") && (ZIP.Length == 5))
    {
        dcListCityDataContext dc = new dcListCityDataContext();
        if (dc.City.Where(c => c.ZIP.Equals(ZIP)).Count() > 0)
        {
            string province = dc.City.Where(c => c.ZIP.Equals(CAP)).First().ID_PROVINCE.ToUpper();
            if (province != null)
            {
                return provincia;
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Server Save Click:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string result = null;

        // HERE IS THE PROBLEM, BECAUSE I HAVE THE WRONG VALUE 
        // IN txtProvince.Text IF I CHANGE THE ZIP CODE AND CLICK
        // DIRECTLY ON THE SAVE BUTTON

        Save(txtProvince.Text, ddlCity.SelectedItem.ToString(), txtZip.Text, txtAddress.Text);
        lblError.Text = "";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem like this like Jquery onchange works. May be it fire only when losing focus. May be you can try use  event [OnkeyUp](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/). This will update the field on any key pressed in the corresponding field.

Updated on comment:
There are performance penalty using OnKeyUp but for small application, it's just fine !!!

Comment: It fire in both cases, because in both cases it's losing focus, and in both cases I could phisically see the textbox province value changing on the screen, only inside the button click function it's still having the old value only if clicking directly on the button after change the ZIP text, seems a timing problem. I think about the OnKeyUp alternative, but it seems to me like losing performance, increasing the number of ajax calling, or is not?

Comment: I don't think that it's a timing problem. I had OnChange event behave the same. Must of time OnkeyUp can just be fine. About performance, Its losing performance but if you are not on a really High-load application, i should be fine at the beginning. Some optimizations can be done after your application growth in size of request per second..

Comment: Yes, probably is ok, even better moving the zip length control from the web method to the jQuery change function, having less useless ajax calling.. But I really don't understand how could not it be a timing problem.. I mean that if I change the zip text, click some point outside of it, and then the button, I have the 2 event, client jquery change and server button click, fired separately. Doing the other way (change zip text and directly clicking on button) they fired together at same time, so when the button click start the text change still has not finished his job and find the old value..